# Type into a textbox which has an overlaying div css

Tags: html, css

How to type into a text box or click a button ,which has a overlaying div. I need to access the text box even though there is a div or image over it.Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Comment: Check the z-index of the elements...

Comment: Are you saying that you need to access an HTML element which is inside a <div>.

Comment: no div is floating above the input element. it an absolutely positioned div.

Comment: Yes i tried z-index,but not working.

Comment: Thank you Codelord i didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

This will make any mouse event "fall through" the element.

> **Note:** however, that this will be applied to all child elements too, so
>   any element you might want to click (a link or so) will be
>   inaccessible.